# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to for making single page application in which when I try to append div element to the page I am getting an error :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null

here is my javascript code

```
function load_mailbox(mailbox) {

  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-error').style.display = 'none';


  // Show the mailbox name
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;

  // list of mails
  fetch(`/emails/${mailbox}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(emails => {
      // Print emails
      var x = emails['length'];
      for (i=0;i<x;i++){
        const emailele = document.createElement('div');
        emailele.setAttribute("style","border: 1px solid black;border-radius:5px");
        emailele.setAttribute("id",`${emails[i].id}`);
        if (mailbox == 'inbox' || mailbox == 'archived'){
          emailele.innerHTML = (`<p><strong>${emails[i].sender}</strong></p><p>${emails[i].subject}</p><p>${emails[i].timestamp}</p>`);
        }
        if (mailbox == 'inbox' && `${emails[i].read}`){
          emailele.setAttribute("style","background-color:#cfcfcf");
        }
        if (mailbox == 'sent'){
          emailele.innerHTML = (`<p><strong>${emails[i].recipients}</strong></p><p>${emails[i].subject}</p><p>${emails[i].timestamp}</p>`);
        }
        document.querySelector('#emails-view-i').append(emailele);
      }
      console.log(emails);

      // ... do something else with emails ...
  });
}
```

and here is my HTML

```
<div id="emails-view">
      <div id="emails-view-i"></div>
    </div>
```

please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here

```
document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;
```

you are setting the html of the root element. So you are overwriting the element, you want to append to and on appending, it can't find the element anymore.

So:

```
document.querySelector('#emails-view-i')
```

is null and you are trying to run .append of null.

So either do something like that:

```
<div id="emails-view"></div>
<div id="emails-view-i"></div>
```

or e.g.:

```
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML + `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;
```

or add another html element to add that headline to inside of the "emails-view" like:

```
<div id="emails-view">
  <div id="emails-view-headline"></div>
  <div id="emails-view-i"></div>
</div>
```

and then:

```
document.querySelector('#emails-view-headline').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;
```

to keep that element.
Hope that helped.

Comment: thank you so much! I tried last suggestion and it worked!